# How do I check if a child exists in the a branch in the database so that I can return values based on that child

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[UI from using the code i mention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwdmj.png)
I have my database set up like this:

root

```
-Students
    -user1
        -name
        -pass
        -etc...
    -user2

-Admin
    -admin1
```

I want to check if the current user is an admin or a student so that i can go to a certain reference in the database

This is my code:

```
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Students").child(user.getUid());

    reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            lastName = dataSnapshot.child("lastName").getValue().toString();
            studentID = dataSnapshot.child("studentID").getValue().toString();
            email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
            password = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue().toString();
            confirmPassword = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue().toString();
            inputStudentID.getEditText().setText(studentID);
            inputName.getEditText().setText(name);
            inputLastName.getEditText().setText(lastName);
            inputEmail.getEditText().setText(email);
            inputPassword.getEditText().setText(password);
            inputConfirmPassword.getEditText().setText(confirmPassword);


        }
```

to get the students info I have to do

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Students").child(user.getUid());
```

but if I were to log on as an admin how would I go to that branch and display their info. I've already tried using an if statement with

```
dataSnapshot.child("Students").hasChild(user.getUID)
```

with the reference of

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
```

to see if the user logged in is in the student branch but that didn't work.

[UI for both admin and student with the code in picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JST0q.png)

[Code for image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XLn1.png)

Comment: What didn't work about what you tried? What specific line of code didn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: None of the admins info was displayed unlike it would with the students info @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo  Ive added pictures for reference

Comment: @Spencer I'm not seeing the code where you are trying to get the admins. I have a hard time understanding the question.

Comment: @AlexMamo The datasnapshot is pulling the admins info from the database just like it would with the students. its inside the event listener

Comment: Yeah thats what i want it to do but none of the info is being pulled

Comment: @AlexMamo I figured out the answer to my problem. I read one of your other answers to another post and it looked like I had to use a call back function since the data was asynchronous

Comment: @Spencer Good to hear that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see if a child exists in the branch of a node and run your code based on that, you have to use a call back function.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774) article for reference